# Why can I not see LocalLow and Local when I type in %AppData% into the Windows 7 Start Button Search, and how can I fix this issue?

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

I typed `%AppData%` into the search box in Windows 7 that I get when when I click the Start Button. For some reason, all I see is the `Roaming` folder, even though I have confirmed that `LocalLow` and `Local` folders do exist. Why are LocalLow and Local folders missing from the search box, and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Local` and `LocalLow` are not actually in `%AppData%`. As Hand-E-Food said, `%AppData%` = `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming`.

Use `%userprofile%\appdata\locallow` and either `%userprofile%\appdata\local` or `%localappdata%` or `%userprofile%\appdata\` (make sure to add the trailing slash or it won't show up). This also works in Windows 10.

There is no variable (eg `%LocalAppDataLow%`) by default that points to the low-privilege local profile, but you could easily [create one for yourself](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-localappdata-environment-variable-in-windows-xp/) (you can also create a `localappdata` variable in XP; for that matter, you can create all sorts of envvar shortcuts to different parts of your file-system).

Comment: I was just doing a web-search to see if there's been any discussion about environment-variables for LocalLow and found my way back here. (Fortunately this time, my answer was short so I saw my avatar so  I didn't like the answer and go to up-vote the answer only to realize it was my own, like has happened surprisingly often. ) Anyway, I was going to mention my current solution of just using `%localappdata%low` as a more-or-less reliable hack (it's possible but unlikely the folders will be in different locations). It looks like Wolfgang already mentioned it a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to quickly get to the AppData\Locallow folder, you can press `Windows-Key + R` and then enter `%localappdata%low`
This should directly open a new Explorer window with the AppData\Locallow folder for you.

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I hear about this! It works!

Comment: This is what I currently do (aside from manually making an environment variable). It's a hack, but it's going to be reliable 99.99(more 9s)% of the time since the folders will almost never be in different locations (even though it's possible). It should work for most purposes (eg batch-files).  Whether it works in programs depends on the program, so you'll just have to test it. 

Answer (score 3):

Because %AppData% points to:

```
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming
```

not

```
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData
```

From the command line, type `Set (variablename)` to see what a variable is declared as, or just `Set` to see all variable declarations.